# How can iodine(I) cations be produced in this reaction if no additional acid is added?

Tags: redox, aromatic-compounds

In laboratory, we had to synthesize an aromatic compound and identify it. The chemical reaction involved salicylamid, $\ce{NaI}$ and $\ce{NaClO}$. The solvent is ethanol.

First, we dissolved the salicylamid with the ethanol. Then we added the NaI. When the mixture was homogeneous, we let it cool down to 0 °C. Once the mixture reached that temperature, we quickly added the NaClO.

We figured out that for the salicylamid to react, we needed an $\ce{I+}$.
Here's how we think we can obtain the $\ce{I+}$:

$$\ce{NaI -> Na+ + I-}\tag{1}$$

$$\ce{NaClO -> Na+ + ClO-}\tag{2}$$

$$\ce{ClO- + I- + 2H+ -> I+ + Cl- + H2O}\tag{3}$$

It seems to be the easiest way to obtain the $\ce{I+}$. However, isn't it impossible for the ethanol to release an $\ce{H+}$? Isn't ethanol neutral? How can the ethanol reacts with the $\ce{NaI}$ and the $\ce{NaClO}$?

PS: Sorry if the terms may not be the correct ones. English isn't my first language.

Edit: Since ethanol is only the solvent and isn't involved in the reaction, how can we obtain an $\ce{I+}$?

Is it like this?

$$\ce{2NaI + NaClO -> NaCl + Na2O + 2I+}\tag{1}$$

Comment: Ethanol doesn't react appreciably. It's the solvent for the reaction.

Comment: Thank you! So the reaction only involves the NaI and the NaClO?

Comment: If you need acidic conditions, could you not add a soluble acid?

Comment: We get to acidify the mixture later. But there's somehow a reaction with the NaI and the NaOCl (maybe the salicylamid). When we add the NaOCl, the mixture turns dark red and after more than 5 minutes of vigorous swirling of the flask, it turns pale green.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple reasons why this works.

- While ethanol may be a very weak acid, there should be a non-neglegible concentration of deprotonated ethanol molecules at any time which is enough to give a nonzero fraction of $\ce{I+}$.
- As $\ce{I+}$ is consumed in the reaction, protons should again be released. Unfortunately, it is only one per $\ce{I+}$, so the process is not entirely catalytic. However:
- Salicylamid is a phenol and phenols are acidic. The phenol will be deprotonated and supply even more excess protons.

You should also pretend you never wrote anything about $\ce{Na2O}$ in ethanolic solution. This will happen:

$$\ce{Na2O + 2 EtOH -> 2 NaOEt + H2O}$$